# Google amp html validator doesn't see mobile page

Tags: mobile, amp-html

I am working on a news website, trying to implement amp. We are using Mobile_Detect.php to serve desktop pages to desktop and tablets, and mobile version to mobile phones and that works OK, our pages are mobile friendly according to Google for some time now, no problem.

Now, I started to enter the code for amp pages and encountered a situation I can' resolve. URL for the amp version have .amp at the end. Depending on the user's device, we are generating the page from the database and serving different pages to different devices.

Now, PageSpeed Insights and Mobile-Friendly Test shows that the page is mobile friendly but amp validator is pulling the desktop page, I can see by the source code it prints out, instead of a mobile page. I'm on the desktop, Chrome, but I'd expect it to work with mobile pages.

You can see that here:  https://validator.ampproject.org/#url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.poandpo.com%2Fbusineasdfasdfas-usual%2Fpublic-housadfadf-kong-972016223.amp

I installed Chrome amp extension and it says "AMP available" but when I click on it it also pulls the desktop version of the page and it's blank. I would expect the extension to load the mobile page but it doesn't.

We do have links canonical and amphtml, that's why the extension says there is an amp page.

So, how to tell validator to pull the mobile version of the page?  The amp implementation is not done yet and I know there are some things missing, but without a validator is a bit hard to program.

Another interesting things is that when I open "Inspect" in Chrome and toggle to responsive design, it shows the mobile version of the webpage correctly. It also says "Powered by amp" and shows no errors although there are errors because we didn't even implemented all tags.

If anybody has any suggestion how to make amp validator to show the mobile page  I'd appreciate that. Thank you.

Comment: I guess your website redirects users by their usergent. And your website redirects the "amp validator" to the desktop page.

Answer (score 2):

I had a quick look at your pages but it appears that the amphtml reference but there appears to be a problem in the URL you are generating in the `href=` field. If you take a close look, the AMP URL is missing a '/'.

Broken: http://www.poandpo.com/business-as-usualmexicans-work-longest-hours-germans-the-least-97201645.amp

Works: http://www.poandpo.com/business-as-usual/mexicans-work-longest-hours-germans-the-least-97201645.amp

Comment: Thank you. That wasn't the reason but you're right that something was wrong with the code, I had to dig deeper and solved that part. Now I have a problem with "The tag 'head > style[amp-boilerplate] - old variant' is deprecated..." but that's another story. :)